# On the prime factorization of $n$ and the quantity $J = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)}$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with *special prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

By the definition of a *perfect number* $N$, we have $\sigma(N)=2N$.  Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and because the divisor sum $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function, it follows that
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2.$$

Now, just like when solving equations in terms of one variable, one should solve the equality
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=2 q^k n^2$$
in terms of one of the expressions.

If one solves for $n$, that introduces a square-root, and takes one out of the integers.  If one solves for $q$, it introduces a $k$th root, and also takes one out of the integers.  One should not solve for $\sigma(q^k)$, since that quantity can already be re-expressed in terms of $q$ and $k$ as
$$\sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1},$$
if needed.  So, the more natural quantity to solve for is $\sigma(n^2)$.

Indeed, throughout [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116), we implicitly rely on the simple equality
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{2q^k n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}. \tag{1}$$
Unfortunately, this seems to introduce fractions.  To avoid that, we can use prime factorizations, as follows.  Write the prime factorization of $n$ as
$$n = {p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m},$$
for some unique odd primes $3 \leq p_1 < \ldots < p_m$, and for some positive integer exponents $a_1, \ldots, a_m$.  Since both sides of $(1)$ are integers, and since $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ with $q$ prime, we know that
$$\sigma(q^k) = 2 {p_1}^{b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{b_m}$$
for some nonnegative integers $0 \leq b_i \leq 2a_i$.  Thus, we have
$$\sigma(n^2) = q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}.$$

Note that the only other facts about odd perfect numbers that we use in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116) are that $b_i < 2a_i$ for at least one index $i$, and that $q$ is different from the $p_i$'s.

---

With this information, we immediately see that
$$G := \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left(2 {p_1}^{b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{b_m},q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)},$$
$$H := \gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left({p_1}^{2a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m}, q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m},$$
and
$$I := \gcd\left(n,\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left({p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m}, q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$

---

The following are excerpts from a referee report on a closely related paper:

> Notice that these equalities are not complicated, do not introduce extraneous information, and flow naturally (by replacing quantities in terms of more fundamental information).

> Now, Lemma 2.1 follows immediately from the fact that for any two integers $a$ and $b$, we have
> $$\min(b,2a-b) + 2a-b = 2\min(a,2a-b).$$

> Lemma 2.2 is even faster, and follows from the fact that
> $$\min(b,2a-b) \leq \min(a,2a-b) \leq 2a-b.$$

> The quantity $J$, defined in Lemma 2.3, is unnecessary and can also be expressed in terms of a prime factorization.

---

Here is our:

> **QUESTION:** What is the prime factorization for
> $$J = \frac{H}{I} = \frac{I}{G} = \frac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)}?$$

---

**OUR ATTEMPT**

We realized that, since the prime factorizations for $H$ and $I$ are given as follows:
$$H = {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}$$
and
$$I = {p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)},$$
then we have
$$J = \frac{H}{I} = \frac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)} = \frac{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}}.$$

**Alas, this is where we get stuck, as we do not know how to simplify**
$$J = \frac{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, and uses the fact that:

> For any two integers $a$ and $b$, we have
> $$\min(b,2a-b) + 2a-b = 2\min(a,2a-b).$$

---

So, we have
$$J = \frac{H}{I} = \frac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)} = \frac{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}}.$$

But using the identity above, we have
$$2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1) = \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1) - \min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1) \tag{2}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m) = \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m) - \min(b_m,2a_m - b_m). \tag{3}$$

Since
$$J = \frac{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}} = {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}$$
then by $(2)$ and $(3)$, we obtain
$$J = {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}$$
$$= {p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1) - \min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m) - \min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$

Comment: In particular, since $n={p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m}$ and because $J = \dfrac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)}$, then we have
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right) = \dfrac{n}{J} = \dfrac{{p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)-\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)-\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)}}$$
from which it follows that
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right) = {p_1}^{a_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1) + \min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m) + \min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$

Comment: This last expression for $\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)$ can be re-expressed as
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)=\dfrac{n}{J}=\dfrac{{p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m}}{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}}$$
from which it follows that
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right) = {p_1}^{b_1 - a_1 + \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots  {p_m}^{b_m - a_m + \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$